# inner product space operations(proving polar coordinates)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, problem-solving

Let V be an inner product space over F. Prove the polar identities: for al $x,y$ $\in V, <x,y>=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^4 I^k ||x+i^k y||^2$ if $F=C$,where $i^2=-1$.

I am trying to break the right hand side individually, but have some trouble with operations.

For the first one and the second
$$1). i||x+iy||^2=i <x+iy,x+iy>=i <x,x>+i<iy,x>+i<x,iy>+i<iy,iy>=i||x^2||+-<y,x>+...$$
$$2). -||x-y||^2=||x||^2-||y||^2+...$$

question: I am not sure how to break open the brackets, need some help with operations. I will then try to do the rest by my self. I am not so used to the conjugate symmetry thing so have hard time dealing with imaginary i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the convention that $\langle ax,y \rangle = a\langle x,y\rangle$, so that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is linear in the first slot (and conjugate-linear in the second).

Note that
$$
\|x + i^k y\|^2 = 
\langle x + i^ky, x + i^ky \rangle \\
= 
\langle x, x \rangle + 
\langle x,i^ky \rangle + \langle i^k y, x \rangle + \langle i^ky, i^k y \rangle\\
= \langle x,x \rangle + i^{-k}\langle x,y \rangle + i^k\langle y,x \rangle + \langle y,y\rangle.
$$
Multiplying by $i^{k}$ gives us
$$
i^{k}\|x + i^k y\|^2
= i^k\langle x,x \rangle + \langle x,y \rangle + i^{2k}\langle y,x \rangle + i^k\langle y,y\rangle.
$$

Comment: so if we take constants out of the right side of the inner product, that has to be a conjugate? I mean you take out $i^k$ from y, then it becomes $i^{-k}$.

Comment: That's exactly right